# Python Json Grouping with individuals

Tags: python

Here is some demo data

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "ABC Corporation",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "company": "ABC Corporation",
    "email": "jane.smith@example.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Michael",
    "last_name": "Johnson",
    "company": "ABC Corporation",
    "email": "michael.johnson@example.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Emily",
    "last_name": "Brown",
    "company": "BestCo",
    "email": "emily.brown@example.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "first_name": "David",
    "last_name": "Lee",
    "company": "BestCo",
    "email": "david.lee@example.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "first_name": "Sophia",
    "last_name": "Wang",
    "company": "Innovate Solutions",
    "email": "sophia.wang@example.com"
  }
]
```

I want to group with individuals until it finished grouping by companies single item only. Like its output below

```
{
  "group1": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "company": "ABC Corporation",
      "email": "john.doe@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Emily",
      "last_name": "Brown",
      "company": "BestCo",
      "email": "emily.brown@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "first_name": "Sophia",
      "last_name": "Wang",
      "company": "Innovate Solutions",
      "email": "sophia.wang@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "group2": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "company": "ABC Corporation",
      "email": "jane.smith@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "first_name": "David",
      "last_name": "Lee",
      "company": "BestCo",
      "email": "david.lee@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "group3": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Michael",
      "last_name": "Johnson",
      "company": "ABC Corporation",
      "email": "michael.johnson@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

in python

Comment: It is not necessarily safe to assume that your JSON data is ordered.  You might want to sort that list by "company" before grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `itertools.groupby` + `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest

lst = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "company": "ABC Corporation",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "company": "ABC Corporation",
        "email": "jane.smith@example.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Michael",
        "last_name": "Johnson",
        "company": "ABC Corporation",
        "email": "michael.johnson@example.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Emily",
        "last_name": "Brown",
        "company": "BestCo",
        "email": "emily.brown@example.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "first_name": "David",
        "last_name": "Lee",
        "company": "BestCo",
        "email": "david.lee@example.com",
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "first_name": "Sophia",
        "last_name": "Wang",
        "company": "Innovate Solutions",
        "email": "sophia.wang@example.com",
    },
]

out = {}
for i, t in enumerate(
    zip_longest(
        *(
            list(g)
            for _, g in groupby(
                sorted(lst, key=lambda k: k["company"]), lambda k: k["company"]
            )
        )
    ),
    1,
):
    out[f"group{i}"] = [v for v in t if v is not None]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "group1": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "company": "ABC Corporation",
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Emily",
            "last_name": "Brown",
            "company": "BestCo",
            "email": "emily.brown@example.com",
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Sophia",
            "last_name": "Wang",
            "company": "Innovate Solutions",
            "email": "sophia.wang@example.com",
        },
    ],
    "group2": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "company": "ABC Corporation",
            "email": "jane.smith@example.com",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "David",
            "last_name": "Lee",
            "company": "BestCo",
            "email": "david.lee@example.com",
        },
    ],
    "group3": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Johnson",
            "company": "ABC Corporation",
            "email": "michael.johnson@example.com",
        }
    ],
}
```